# YA MySQL Error #1064 in CALL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I've created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ABON_PLATA`(DATE_BAL1 datetime)
BEGIN
        DECLARE IMSI1 varchar(6);
        DECLARE DATE1 datetime;
        DECLARE ID_U1 integer;
        DECLARE PAY1 double;
        DECLARE PAYSUM double;
        DECLARE OLD1 double;
        DECLARE REASON1 varchar(16);
        DECLARE FLAG integer DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID_U FROM podkl_otkl_uslug WHERE IMSI1=IMSI;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET FLAG=1;

OPEN C1;
     REPEAT
        FETCH C1 INTO ID_U1;
                IF FLAG=0 THEN
                SELECT SUM(PAY) INTO PAY1 FROM uslugi WHERE ID_U1=ID_U AND DATE_PODKL<DATE_BAL1 AND DATE_OTKL IS NULL;
                SET REASON1 = 'ABON PLATA';
                SET DATE1 = DATE_BAL1;
                SET PAYSUM = `NEW`-PAY1;
                SET OLD1 = `NEW`;
              END IF;
        INSERT history (`DATE`, REASON, `NEW`, OLD, IMSI) VALUES (DATE1, REASON1, PAYSUM, OLD1, IMSI1);
        UNTIL FLAG=1
     END REPEAT;
CLOSE C1;
END
```

It is used to simulate subscribtion fee of mobile operator. As I am trying to call it, I get the notorious error:

```
CALL ABON_PLATA(2013-07-07 12:00:00);

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:00:00)' at line 1
```

Considering it is an error at line 1, I get extremely confused. What super obvious am I missing?

Comment: shouldn't INSERT history be INSERT INTO history

Comment: @Satya, the `INTO` keyword is optional.  See the official syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datetime literals must be in quotes.

```
CALL ABON_PLATA('2013-07-07 12:00:00');
```

The reason it reports an error at line 1 is that it's the `CALL` line that contains an error.  It has nothing to do with your procedure code, because the error happens before it can even call your procedure.

---

Re your comment:

> Thread stack overrun: 6892 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

This indicates that your MySQL has a configured value of `thread_stack` that is too small to run statements in Stored Procedures.  This can happen, for example, if you use the **my-small.cnf** configuration file that is bundled with some releases of MySQL.

Increase the value of `thread_stack` in your configuration file.  The default is 256K, and it's only the my-small.cnf that sets it lower.  There has been a [bug logged](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56744) about this setting being too low.

Don't forget to restart your MySQL service after you make this change to the config file.

Comment: Many thanks, but as usual more debugging leads to more errors. Upon correcting it, I am getting the following error: 
 
`Thread stack overrun:  6892 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.`